# PDF document is not loading

Tags: pdf, cakephp-3.0

I am using [CakePdf](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf) to my project. I have install it via composer. But it is not loading the document.
Check *error.log* file. Nothing found.

Browser send the following message:

> **Firefox**:
>
> This pdf document might not be displayed correctly.
>
> **Chrome**:
>
> Error
>
> Failed to load PDF document.

Here is my code:

```
// AppController.php
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    }
}


// bootstrap.php
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.mPdf',
    'margin' => [
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ],
    'orientation' => 'landscape',
    'pageSize' => 'Legal',
    'download' => true
]);

Plugin::load('CakePdf', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);


// routes.php
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    // enabled extensions
    $routes->addExtensions(['pdf']);
}


// ProductsController.php
public function viewPdf($id = null)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->options([
        'pdfConfig' => [
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id
        ]
    ]);
}
```

I have created **Template/Products/pdf/view_pdf.ctp** and **Template/Layout/pdf/default.ctp**

I cakephp version is 3.5.2

I couldn't get, where is the probleme. Please help me.